# Почему идентификатор не найден?

Tags: delphi, lazarus, pascal

Есть приложение с больше, чем 9ooo форм. При нажатии на кнопочку надо показать form2. Пишу в событии:

```
form2.show;
```

В ответ ошибка:

> form2 - identifier not found

В чем проблема?

Пишу в lazarus, в delphi все работало.

Comment: Больше кода. Непонятно, в каком контексте выполняется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего, в блоке uses забыли добавить ссылку на файл, в котором обявлен form2.

Comment: Спасибо, действительно.